# How to show Virtual Keyboard for .NET MAUI 6.0 application on Windows Tablet programmatically?

Tags: c#, maui

The application I am writing is in Visual Studio 2022 on .NET MAUI 6.0.
It's being designed to run on a Windows 10 Tablet.

I am attempting to enable the virtual keyboard on this windows tablet upon focusing an entry.
I cannot seem to find anyway to get the windows virtual keyboard to automatically pop up programmatically.

The reason for not just pressing the keyboard button in the bottom right is that I am designing this for users who are not used to that. They're simple and they're stubborn, they just want the keyboard to appear.

Trying to run the osk.exe pops the keyboard up as a different application in an odd location on the screen, so:
A. it blots out the entry it's supposed to be interacting with and
B. When you exit the keyboard, it reenters the application, causing it to refocus the entry, reenabling the osk.exe and bringing it back up.

Comment: Start by upgrading your project from 6 to 7.

Comment: Are you testing on the tablet? If there is no physical keyboard attached, then the virtual keyboard should pop up automatically when an entry has focus. If it doesn’t pop up, then Windows thinks there is a physical keyboard attached.

Comment: @H.A.H. There are reasons I cannot upgrade to 7 from 6, mostly because my corporate overlords saw the "Long Term Support" tag and wanted that option. Sorry, but I cannot upgrade.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am indeed testing on the tablet. Pressing entries on other applications brings up the keyboard like normal, it's only mine, so I'm thinking the keyboard detection is correctly detecting that I do not have a keyboard.

Comment: @JosephFoulk No need to apologize for incompetence. This long term support ended "May 8, 2023". MAUI NET 7.0 ends May 14, 2024. Read this here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/maui.

Comment: @H.A.H. While I was unaware of this info, it is also not my decision. VisStudio lists it as LTS which is usually a 3 year cycle. I appreciate directing me to this page, but it does not solve the base issue or even mildly address it. Do you have a link to any specific logs where this issue is addressed in a changeover between 6 and 7? I would appreciate some help with my issue rather than an attempt to get me to do something I cannot do. I'm doing the best with what tools I am being forced to use. Thank you.

Comment: They may not be aware that, while .Net 6 itself has longer-term support than .Net .7, Maui on .Net 6 **does not**. Maui was too new; it has various issues under .Net 6. I’d say there is an informal consensus (among developers who use Maui) that Maui should not have been declared production ready at the time it was. AFAIK, the consistent advice from the experts here using Maui is: “Upgrade to .Net 7; plan to upgrade to .Net 8, whenever it has General Availability release”. .Net 8 will be the real long-term-support version of Maui. Maui on .Net 6 was too early. An over-promise by Microsoft.

Comment: I recommend creating an issue at `github maui issues` regarding long term support of maui 6 vs 7 vs 8. Maybe there is a commitment to backport fixes to 6. Or you might get even more agreement to abandon 6.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Ohhh, I see, .NET 6.0 itself has the support, not .NET MAUI 6. I see the difference now. I'm going to have to do some digging then to pick up some proof that I should upgrade to 7. I'm dealing with a group of people who subscribe to the old ways, it has taken a lot to convince them to move to MAUI for any software at all. That being said, my issue still stands. does anyone happen to know how I could potentially fix this issue in 6. A move to 7 will take me months to convince them. If I'm seen in 7 before then, I get fired.

Comment: @JosephFoulk What proof do you need? Out of support. It is not getting updates. It is not getting bug fixes. People are not using it, so you have no one to ask anything. And I do not think those guys will fire you. Judging by how clueless they are, they will not even notice it is .NET 7.

Comment: [Microsoft .Net 8 gets November release date, devs hope for stable Maui](https://devclass.com/2023/08/03/microsoft-net-8-gets-november-release-date-devs-hope-for-stable-maui/). That's what you need to target. That is the true "long-term support .Net Maui". I don't know whether this month it is better to do most development on .Net 7 (testing newest features on .Net 8 Preview), or go straight to Preview. Its a shame Microsoft fooled themselves (or however you want to label this misfire) that .Net Maui 6 was a useable General Release product. But it is what it is.